# Ansible subelements lookup expects a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have a variable/dictionary file as below:

```
cafu_analyze_bidprice:
  artifacts_name:
    - "forecast-measures-read-deploy"
    - "forecast-measures-finalizer-deploy"
  group_id: "com.lufthansa.cobra.cafu"

cafu_measurement:
  artifacts_name:
    - "forecast-exporter-read-deploy"
  group_id: "com.lufthansa.cobra.cafu"
```

and playbook as below:

```
- name: Get deployable artifact from artifactory and copy
  maven_artifact:
    validate_certs: false
    group_id: "{{ item.0.group_id }}"
    artifact_id: "{{ item.1 }}"
    version: "{{ version }}"
    repository_url: http://10.127.130.82:8081/artifactory/cafu
    dest: "/opt/cafu/target-test"
    classifier: "exec"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ module_name }}"
    - artifacts_name
```

for which I am passing module name as variable:

```
ansible-playbook -C cafu-deploy.yml -i hosts -e module_name=cafu_analyze_bidprice -e version=1.1.17-SNAPSHOT
```

Getting below error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got
>   'cafu_analyze_bidprice'"}

Please help if I am doing something wrong, task is to get module name from command line and than use those as dictionary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes:

- You are passing a string (`cafu_analyze_bidprice`) instead of a reference to the variable named `cafu_analyze_bidprice`,
- Using `subelements` lookup does not fit this use case, because you don't have a list of dictionaries.

What you should be doing instead:

- use [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/lookup/vars.html) to refer to a variable with a name stored in another variable (you use `module_name`),
- iterate over the list defined in the `artifacts_name` key of the above lookup result.

As you also use `group_id` key, you can use a helper variable (called `my_var` in the example below) to avoid calling the lookup twice:

```
- name: Get deployable artifact from artifactory and copy
  maven_artifact:
    validate_certs: false
    group_id: "{{ my_var.group_id }}"
    artifact_id: "{{ item }}"
    version: "{{ version }}"
    repository_url: http://10.127.130.82:8081/artifactory/cafu
    dest: "/opt/cafu/target-test"
    classifier: "exec"
  loop: "{{ my_var.artifacts_name }}"
  vars:
    my_var: "{{ lookup('vars', module_name) }}"
```